# Thunderbird 37.1.0 disable Send Now keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, thunderbird

I would like to disable the Send Message Now shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in Thunderbird 31.7.0. I have installed the Keyconfig add on as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_customizing-keyboard-shortcuts).

However, this particular shortcut is not on the list. This is arguably THE WORST shortcut combination imaginable. The number of times I have sent an incomplete email by mistake is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed keyconfig, but you can't find the "Send Now" option:

1) Open Thunderbird

2) Start composing a new message (in a new window)

3) In the main Thunderbird window, go to the Tools menu > Keyconfig

4) At the top of the Keyconfig window, there is a dropdown box, with one entry for each open Thunderbird window
for example:
- Inbox
- Write (no subject)
- Keyconfig

5) Choose the "Write . . ." window in the Keyconfig dropdown box

6) Send Now should now be listed in the Keyconfig listbox

7) Select Send Now, and click Disable